# Windows 10 Batch File - IF Usage

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a simple batch file that contains a single line:

```
if not exist "C:\users\fred\desktop\b\" ( md "C:\users\fred\desktop\b" ) &&copy /Y "C:\users\fred\desktop\b.txt" "C:\users\fred\desktop\b\"
```

You can see the intent - if a particular folder doesn't exist on the desktop, create it. Regardless of whether the folder already existed, copy a particular file into that folder.

Note that there are two commands on the same line - the IF conditional and the copy command, using the "&&" operator.

But when I execute it, it only ever works if the folder doesn't exist. Then it creates the folder and copies the file to it. If the folder already exists, then it does nothing. It's like it thinks the whole thing is in the IF condition, regardless of the '(' and ')' around the folder creation.

I would swear that this worked on earlier versions of Windows...but I could be wrong.

FWIW, Windows 10 32 bit.

Comment: `md "C:\users\fred\desktop\b & copy etc` Testing wastes battery power and speed. Also easier `xcopy c:\windows\win.ini "%userprofile%\desktop\mytestfolder\*.*"`

Answer (score 2):

The code you post did not work in previous Windows versions either.

As written, your code says *if this folder does not exist, make the directory and copy the file*. If the directory exists, it never gets to the *copy the file* part.

What you want is for the copy to work regardless of whether the directory had to be created or not, so you need to use two separate lines.

```
if not exist "C:\users\fred\desktop\b\" md "C:\users\fred\desktop\b" 
copy /Y "C:\users\fred\desktop\b.txt" "C:\users\fred\desktop\b\"
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments by CatCat, how about using `XCopy` instead?

*With a trailing backslash on the destination, it will be created if it doesn't already exist.*

Example:

```dos
Xcopy "%UserProfile%\Desktop\b.txt" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\b\" /H /K /Q /R /Y
```

*You can adjust the options as necessary, enter `XCopy /?` for the usage information.*

Comment: Thank you. perfect solution. I don't know how to mark a solution as correct on here.

Comment: Just click on the large check mark to the left of the respective answer.

Answer (score 0):

The then-part of an `if` command extends to the end of the line and may include several commands separated by `&`, `&&` or `||`. This has been so since the days of Windows NT, when `cmd.exe` was first introduced.

To restrict the then-part and keep the script on one single line you can place the `if` in a parenthesized compound command:

```
( if not exist "C:\users\fred\desktop\b\" md "C:\users\fred\desktop\b" ) & copy /y "C:\users\fred\desktop\b.txt" "C:\users\fred\desktop\b\"
```

- `( if not exist "directory" md "directory" )`

  By placing the `if` in a parenthesized compound command we ensure that the then-part does not extend to the end of the line
- `&`

  Command separator.
- `copy /y "file" "directory"`

  Executed regardless of the exit status of the previous command.